# Expand/collapse content one at a time only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some really helpful answers to help me use java to expand and collapse content, but now I can't figure out how to make it only expand one at a time... So that when one div is expanded, if you click to expand another one, it collapses the first one. Any ideas? Here's the fiddle and the code. Please help!

http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/248/

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <span>Expand</span>
        </div>

    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

Script :

```
$(".header").click(function () {

        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.text(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: java!=javascript so removed it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $contents = $(".content")
var $headers = $(".header").click(function () {

    var $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    var $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

    $headers.not($header).text("Expand");
    $contents.not($content).stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Evc22/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse You will see a great example of an accordion menu.  You can implement it by just using Bootstrap and the Bootstrap javascript file.  Or you can dig into their code and see how they do it.  I would recommend figuring out how they do it so you can adjust it as needed.  Just because its Bootstrap doesnt mean its best way to do it.